# How can you retrieve a customer's payment methods in Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

I am having an issue retrieving a customer's payment methods within Acumatica.  My code appears below.

```
        AR303010Content AR301000 = context.AR303010GetSchema();
        context.AR303010Clear();
        string[][] AR301000data = context.AR303010Export
        (
            new Command[]
            {
                AR301000.PaymentMethodSelection.ServiceCommands.EveryCustomer,
                AR301000.PaymentMethodSelection.Customer,
                AR301000.PaymentMethodSelection.PaymentMethod,
                AR301000.PaymentMethodSelection.CardAccountNo
            },
            new Filter[]
            {
                new Filter
                {
                    Field = AR301000.PaymentMethodSelection.Customer,
                    Condition = FilterCondition.Equals,
                    Value = "TEST"
                }
            },
            0, false, false

        );
```

The service times out without returning any records.

Answer (score 0):

try to use next approach and remove Filter

```
        new Command[]
        {
```

new Value {Value = "Test", LinkedCommand = AR301000.PaymentMethodSelection.Customer },
                AR301000.PaymentMethodSelection.ServiceCommands.EveryPaymentMethodID,
                AR301000.PaymentMethodSelection.PaymentMethod,
                AR301000.PaymentMethodSelection.CardAccountNo
            }, null